# TCP sockets and connections

Tags: sockets, tcp, connection

Please correct me if i am wrong.

When server runs on a machine, one socket is created which binds itself to the port server is running on and this socket listens for incomming connection. 
When clients connects to server (using server ip and port number), if server accepts the connection, one more socket gets created on server machine on same port (port server is running on) and socket gets bound to client ip and port.
Similarly, on client side, one socket is created.

In this entire process, 3 sockets are created.
1. on server, listening for incomming connections.
2. on server, bound to client ip and port
3. on client, bound to server ip and port.

Am i correct?
I am new to socket programming. Is there any weblink/resources, where i can read basics of socket programming from?

Comment: I have edited the questions. It will be great if you can help me now.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what language you intend to work with. Socket APIs between languages all have their quirks. You stated your understanding of how things work, but your question lacks an actual implementation for us to see where you're getting stuck. I suggest asking another question once you have that, and we'll gladly help you get it working and grasp the fundamentals (provided it's not a duplicate of another question). Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right. I think you can learn pretty much from python docs:

- http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html
- http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. The reason why both server sockets required for TCP are so called is purely historical, there is no connection between the two. They are very different things.